# PowerPointのスライドショーの画面切替タイミングをスライド毎に決められた時間でVBAで自動入力する方法はありますか？

Tags: vba, powerpoint

VBAの全くの初心者です。今回、初めて参加させて頂きます。
よろしくお願い致します。

PowerPointのスライドショー画面切り替え時間をVBAで一度に入力可能なサンプルコードを探しております。

今まではPowerPointのリハーサルで画面の切り替え時間を調整しておりました。
今回はあらかじめ、決められたスライド毎の時間をリハーサル、またはPowerPointで画面入力することなく、VBAにて全て自動で入力を行いたいです。
PowerPointの画面切り替えにて時間設定でスライドごとに入力することは可能ですが、Excelで作った切り替え時間があるので一度にVBAにてExcelから取り込み、最後のmp4の書き出しまで自動化が出来ればと考えております。

宜しくご指導のほど、お願い致します。

下記のような、全スライドを一度に同じ時間で設定する方法は見つけました。
今回はスライド毎に異なる時間をVBAにて一度に設定する方法を教えて頂きたいです。

スライド枚数は通常３０枚前後になりますが、可能であれば実際のサンプルコードとして、今回は３枚のスライドショーの画面切り替えにて各時間を5秒、１０秒、1分３２秒になった場合の実際のコードを教えて頂ければ幸いです。

あらかじめ入力するデータはExcel上で作成済みとします。

- ①スライド番号、②時間

また、サンプルコードが出来た場合には毎回、スライドの枚数や各スライド時間が異なるものを同じようにVBAのコードに埋め込むことになりますが、毎回、機械的に自動化できる何か良い方法などありましたらアイデアも頂きたいと思います。

よろしくお願い致します。

ちなみに下記は全てのスライドを一度に5.5秒で設定しているサンプルでした。

```
Sub 画面切替時間を設定する_全スライド()
　Const SHOW_SEC = 5.5

　Dim sld As Slide

　For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
　With sld.SlideShowTransition
　　.AdvanceOnTime = msoTrue
　　.AdvanceTime = SHOW_SEC
　End With
　Next sld

End Sub
```

Comment: この説明のように個々のページをインデックスを指定して個別に設定すれば良いのでは？ [SlideShowTransition オブジェクト (PowerPoint)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/vba/api/powerpoint.slideshowtransition) そして設定用のデータを構造体等の配列として保持しておいて、任意に指定する.pptファイルのページ数に合わせて適用するプログラムを作成しておくとか。

Comment: スタックオーバーフローへようこそ！他者にとっても有用な良い質問だと思います。歓迎します。しかし申し訳ないのですが、ご質問を拝読してもどの部分で困っているのかが分かりにくく感じました。サンプルコードのマクロは実行できますか？`ActivePresentation.Slides`を個別のスライドに分けるコードは作りましたか？`SHOW_SEC`を5秒、10秒、1分32秒の配列にする方法は分かりますか？Excelのセルをループしながら読み取る箇所で悩んでいますか？[mp4書き出し](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44501417)する処理はWeb検索しましたか？当サイトはQAサイトなので「この要件のサンプルコードがほしい」よりも「ここまで頑張ったけどこのエラーが出るから解決したい」質問の方が的確な回答を得やすいです。不完全なコードでも良いのでぜひサンプルコードを書きなおして試行錯誤し、悩んでいる具体的な経緯を質問文に追記してみてください！